# Gray edges appear when swiping page in Blackberry Jquery Mobile+Phonegap app

Tags: css, cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a Blackberry and Android app using PhoneGap and Jquery mobile together. I don't have any problems with the android version but with Blackberry I'm getting a strange behavior that I don't want to get...

When I scroll/swipe up or down the page moves to that direction as if it were a scroll-able page but IT IS NOT and this creates an "elastic bouncing effect" making appear gray edges up and down of the page ...

I suppose this issue has to do with some CSS bug problem but I haven't been able to figure it out...

Here you have some pictures that help to understand better my problem...

[Image 1](http://imgur.com/3U5y5R6)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbYXE.jpg)

I hope you can help me... Sorry for my bad English btw...

Comment: If you don't end up getting any good responses here, I recommend re-posting your question in the BlackBerry Developer Forums. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Developer-Support-Forums/ct-p/blackberrydev